# Objective-C Changing values of instance variables in method

Tags: objective-c, xcode4

I am write a Objective-C Code on XCode 4.4.
I have a NSMutableArray  as a instance variable of my class k_info
I have defined and synthesized (nonatomic,retain) property by the name of onesplaces too.
I am unable to add a NSMUtableString object in the NSMutableArray onesplaces.
When I try to add it.The size of onesplaces remains 0 and object at zero index obviously remains null.
I tried doing this with and without using "self" key-word but it didnt worked in either case.
My syntax of adding object and printing it is right because when I create a new NSMutableArray test
and try to do the same thing it works for it but not for the instance variable onesplaces.
I cannot proceed any further in my project without solving this issue.please tell me why is it
happening and how should I solve this problem.

-(void)createinfo:(NSMutableArray *)al varsis:(int)vars
    {
      NSMutableString* stes=[[NSMutableString alloc]init];
      stes=(NSMutableString*)@"string0";

```
  [ onesplaces addObject:stes];
  NSLog(@"%u",[onesplaces count]);
  NSLog(@"value is: %@ ",[ onesplaces objectAtIndex:0]);

  [ self.onesplaces addObject:stes];
   NSLog(@"%u",[onesplaces count]);
   NSLog(@"value is: %@ ",[self.onesplaces objectAtIndex:0]);

  NSMutableArray* test=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
  [ test addObject:stes];
   NSLog(@"%u",[test count]);
  NSLog(@"value is: %@ ",[test objectAtIndex:0]);

}
```

Comment: It may be sometime we forget to initialize the array before adding into it. Check if that is the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably forgot to create the array. Somewhere in your code, maybe in your `init` method, you need to create the array before using it.

```
self.onesplaces = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
```

You get `nil` instead of error messages because Objective-C allows you to send messages to nil, which always return nil.

Comment: Yeah that was the problem.I had not initialized the NSMutableArray.Now after creating it.The code is working.thanx a lot

Comment: @ImrozeAslam Glad I could help, and welcome to StackOverflow. It is customary here to "accept" the answer that solved your problem, which will give both you and the answerer better reputation on the site.